# Stuck in developing an interactive USSD app

Tags: android, kotlin, interactive, ussd

Halo great people?

I am using the below code to get, dismiss and toast a USSD response message, However, I would like to interact with the ussd response containing menus or options,

e.g, reply with one in the USSD's edit text and click the send button.

How can I go about this. if you have some reference code, examples, or you can point me in the right direction I'll be very grateful.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Thanks, Keep safe.

class USSDService : AccessibilityService() {

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    val ussdResponse = event!!.text.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
    if( TextUtils.isEmpty(ussdResponse) ) return;
    if (event.className == "android.app.AlertDialog") {
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
        val intent = Intent("com.times.ussd.action.REFRESH")
        intent.putExtra("message", ussdResponse)

        val nodeInfo = event.source
        val list: List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send")
        for (node in list) {

            if (ussdResponse.contains("Select User")){
                /** I would like to perform the setting of text and replying back here... */
            }
        }



        Toast.makeText(this, ussdResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        // 
    }
}

override fun onInterrupt() {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected()
    val info = AccessibilityServiceInfo()
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT
    info.packageNames = arrayOf("com.android.phone")
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC
    serviceInfo = info
}
```

}

/** I found the Following code; */

```
val inputNode = source.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT)
val arguments = Bundle()
```

arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "2")

```
inputNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments)
for (node in list) {                                        
      node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
}
```

Supposed to reply with 6 but returns a null.
There's an exception the input is null.

Anyone seeing where or what I am doin wrong!

Comment: Android doesn't have any APIs for sending USSD codes.  You can try via the dialer, but you're hoping the dialer supports whatever you want to do, which is a crap shoot. Why are you using USSD anyway-  its pretty much a dead protocol at this point, it had some value before mobile web, but the world has moved on.

Comment: Im a trying to develop an app that should run in remote places in Africa without the need of internet connection

Comment: Android really isn't set up to support USSD. You may need to go the route of replacing the entire dialer so you can directly access the telecom stack.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961745/i-there-a-way-to-run-an-interactive-ussd-session-and-hide-the-session-behind-a-l/68148632#68148632)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that this is **NOT** supported for Android below API 5, but runs fine in API 6 and above.